# How do I use a deserialized object c#

Tags: c#, deserialization

I'm trying to implement a function in a console-based game to save the state and load it back if need be via serialization.

If I deserialize an object using `obj = (objType)BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(FileStream);` can i use the methods available to the object by simply doing `obj.objMethod()` or is there another step i'm missing?
For example:

```
Game game = new Game();
```

let's say the game class has a `Map()` method. And I serialize the game object.

```
BinaryFormatter.Serialize(FileStream, game);
```

And I deserialize it

```
Game savedGame = (Game)BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(FileStream);
```

can I do:

```
savedGame.Map();
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. `savedGame` is a `Game`, so of course you can call `Map` on it. What _exactly_ are you worried about?

Comment: When you serialize your complete game object, then yes this should work.

Comment: Before you get too far into what you're doing, have you considered saving the state in a more friendly format? Such as JSON?

Comment: Before posting the question, you should have tried executing the code atleast once and then post specific issue that you face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that in C#. Unlike Typescript or other loosely typed languages, C# actually creates the object and then assigns the values while deserializing.

But before asking the question you should have tried doing this.